# how many out ports a openmax il source component have?

Tags: components, port, openmax

I am testing the `libomxil-bellagio-master` which is a implementation of `openmax-il`.
in this code, I found the source component(path in the source code is `libomxil-bellagio-master/src/base/`) only have one out port.

I have a file with `audio` and `video` . And I want to write a file reader to demux  this file. how many out ports should this file-reader have?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to implement a `demuxer` as an `OMX` component, then your component would ideally have **2** ports viz., one each for `audio` and `video`.